# JavaScript slideshow (start from other slide, depending on day of week)

Tags: javascript, slideshow, slide

I have this slideshow (JS Fidle: https://jsfiddle.net/toon09/zopnqxry/)
Everything works with it, but i want slideshow start depending on day of week and time of the day.

I.e. If today is Monday (from 12pm to 7 am), start from slide 1, if today is monday (from 7 am to 12pm) start slideshow from slide number 2, if today is tuesday, start from slide 3 and etc.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//rotation speed and timer
var speed = 900000000;
var run = setInterval('rotate()', speed);   

//grab the width and calculate left value
var item_width = $('#slides li').outerWidth(); 
var left_value = item_width * (-1); 

//move the last item before first item, just in case user click prev button
$('#slides li:first').before($('#slides li:last'));

//set the default item to the correct position 
$('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});

//if user clicked on prev button
$('#prev').click(function() {

    //get the right position            
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) + item_width;

    //slide the item            
    $('#slides ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 200,function(){    

        //move the last item and put it as first item               
        $('#slides li:first').before($('#slides li:last'));           

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    });

    //cancel the link behavior            
    return false;

});


//if user clicked on next button
$('#next').click(function() {

    //get the right position
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) - item_width;

    //slide the item
    $('#slides ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 200, function () {

        //move the first item and put it as last item
        $('#slides li:last').after($('#slides li:first'));                  

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    });

    //cancel the link behavior
    return false;

});        

//if mouse hover, pause the auto rotation, otherwise rotate it
$('#slides').hover(

    function() {
        clearInterval(run);
    }, 
    function() {
        run = setInterval('rotate()', speed);   
    }
); 

});

//a simple function to click next link
//a timer will call this function, and the rotation will begin :)  
function rotate() {
   $('#next').click();
}
```

html:

```
<div id="carousel">


<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="slides"> 
    <ul>            
        <li>If today monday and its from 12 pm till 7:30 <br>am,start showing from this slide</li>
        <li>If today monday and its from 7:30 am till 11:59 pm,<br>start showing from this slide</li>
        <li>if today is other day of the week<br> (from tuesday to sunday)start slideshow from this slide</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="tarpas"></div>
<div id="buttons1">
    <a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="buttons2">
    <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do that? Can anyone help me pls with this? Tired of searching google :)

Comment: For the record: comments are supposed to explain *why* your code does what it does, not *what* is happening.. If it's not plainly obvious to another programmer then you should aim to refactor your code rather than add comments

Answer (score 0):

I built an example for you, but it is set to go off right now so you can see it work in the fiddle, it is checking the date and time and moving the list element based on it.

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/zopnqxry/3/

```
  <script>
    function today() {
      var d = new Date();
      var h = d.getHours();
      var weekday = new Array(7);
      weekday[0] = "Sunday";
      weekday[1] = "Monday";
      weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
      weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
      weekday[4] = "Thursday";
      weekday[5] = "Friday";
      weekday[6] = "Saturday";

      var n = weekday[d.getDay()];

      var $el = $(li1);

      //if friday after 12o'clock trigger    
      if ((n === "Friday") && (h > 12)) {

        //move element down one step
        $el.next().after($el);
      }
    }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I make an example but it's based on a position.

[Example - https://jsfiddle.net/microThread/h8ncna1v/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/microThread/h8ncna1v/5/)

Ex: 
   Slider 
     -> item 1 [position 0],
     -> item 2[position 1],
     -> item n[position n]

By default all items in the slider are not showing and base on the SliderCronPosition.getDayConfig() you can get the position that you need for the specific interval.

For intervals that are not existing in the config for current day you can specified a default position for that day 
(Ex: 'Saturday'.default.start_position) or in case you current day is not in the config then the system use the 'config.default_start_position'.

```
        var SliderCronPosition = {
        current_cron_info: {
            day: null,
            start_position: null,
            interval_a: null,
            interval_b: null,
        },

        day_name: {
            0: 'Sunday',
            1: 'Monday',
            2: 'Tuesday',
            3: 'Wednesday',
            4: 'Thursday',
            5: 'Friday',
            6: 'Saturday'
        },


        config: {
            default_start_position: 1,

            'Sunday': {
                'intervals': {
                }
            },

            'Monday': {
                'intervals': {
                }
            },

            'Tuesday': {
                'intervals': {
                }
            },

            'Wednesday': {
                'intervals': {
                }
            },

            'Thursday': {
                'intervals': {
                }
            },

            'Friday': {
                'intervals': {
                }
            },

            /* Saturday. */
            'Saturday': {
                'intervals': {
                    /* Interval 1. */
                    0: {
                        'interval_a': '00:00:00',
                        'interval_b': '07:30:00',
                        'start_position': 2
                    },

                    /* Interval 2. */
                    1: {
                        'interval_a': '07:30:00',
                        'interval_b': '23:59:00',
                        'start_position': 2
                    }
                },


                /* Default value for this day. */
                'default': {
                    'start_position': 1
                }
            },


        },


        getDay: function() {
            var d = new Date();

            return d.getDay();
        },


        getDayName: function() {
            return this.day_name[this.getDay()];
        },


        getCurrentDate: function() {
            var d = new Date();

            return (d.getFullYear() + '/' + ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+ '/' + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) );
        },


        getCurrentTime: function() {
            var d = new Date();

            return d.getTime();
        },


        getIntervalTime: function(time) {
            var value = null,
                    d = new Date(this.getCurrentDate() + " " + time);

            if(d instanceof Date && isFinite(d)) {
                value = d.getTime();
            }


            return value;
        },


        getDayConfig: function() {
            var value   = null,
                d       = this.getDayName();


            this.current_cron_info.day              = null;
            this.current_cron_info.start_position   = null;
            this.current_cron_info.interval_a       = null;
            this.current_cron_info.interval_b       = null;


            if(typeof this.config[d] !== 'undefined') {

                if(typeof this.config[d].intervals !== 'undefined') {


                    this.current_cron_info.day = d;


                    for (var i in this.config[d].intervals) {

                        var     interval_a      = this.getIntervalTime(this.config[d].intervals[i].interval_a),
                                interval_b      = this.getIntervalTime(this.config[d].intervals[i].interval_b),
                                current_time    = this.getCurrentTime();

                        switch(true) {
                            case (interval_a !== null && interval_b !== null):
                                if (current_time >= interval_a && current_time <= interval_b) {

                                    this.current_cron_info.interval_a       = this.config[d].intervals[i].interval_a;
                                    this.current_cron_info.interval_b       = this.config[d].intervals[i].interval_b;

                                    value = this.config[d].intervals[i].start_position;
                                }
                            break;


                            case (interval_a !== null && interval_b === null):
                                if (current_time >= interval_a) {

                                    this.current_cron_info.interval_a       = this.config[d].intervals[i].interval_a;
                                    this.current_cron_info.interval_b       = this.config[d].intervals[i].interval_b;

                                    value = this.config[d].intervals[i].start_position;
                                }
                            break;


                            case (interval_a === null && interval_b !== null):
                                if (current_time <= interval_b) {

                                    this.current_cron_info.interval_a       = this.config[d].intervals[i].interval_a;
                                    this.current_cron_info.interval_b       = this.config[d].intervals[i].interval_b;

                                    value = this.config[d].intervals[i].start_position;
                                }
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                }


                /* In case we don't have any value and we have a default value. */
                if(
                        value == null &&
                        typeof this.config[d].default !== 'undefined'
                ) {
                    value = this.config[d].default.start_position;
                }

            }


            value = (value == null) ? this.config.default_start_position : value;

            this.current_cron_info.start_position = value;

            return value;
        }

    };


    $(document).ready(function() {


        var     current_job_info    = $('#current_job_info'),
                slider              = $('#slider'),
                get_start_position  = SliderCronPosition.getDayConfig();

        slider.find('.item').eq( (get_start_position - 1)).show();

        current_job_info.append("Day: " + SliderCronPosition.current_cron_info.day);
        current_job_info.append(" | Slider Position: " + SliderCronPosition.current_cron_info.start_position);
        current_job_info.append(" | Interval A:" + SliderCronPosition.current_cron_info.interval_a);
        current_job_info.append(" | Interval B:" + SliderCronPosition.current_cron_info.interval_b);

    });
```